# Can't use sharedPreference in adListener

Tags: java, android

I want to run an interstitial ad whenever a user closes/leaves a specific fragment. To do this, i run a method, `showIntAd()` in `onDetach()` The test ad showns just fine 
The `Log.i(TAG, "Ad closed");` runs fine, but if i try either `putInt` or `getInt` all code after that won't execute. 
Basically i want to save an int, value 0, to my sharedPreference, `if onAdClosed()` runs

Creation and loading of interstitial ad, and initiation of sharedPreference in onCreate

```
        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

        mInterstitialAd_Arcade = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        mInterstitialAd_Arcade.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_ads_test_id));
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd_Arcade.loadAd(adRequest);
```

On Detach

```
 @Override
public void onDetach(){
    super.onDetach();
    showIntAd();
}
```

Method of showing ad

```
private void showIntAd(){
            int interstitial_counter = 
            mSharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.pref_arcade_interstitial_counter), 0);
            if (interstitial_counter >= 15){
                if (mInterstitialAd_Arcade.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd_Arcade.show();
                }
                    mInterstitialAd_Arcade.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onAdOpened(){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Ad opened");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode){
                        Log.e(TAG,  "Ad Failed to load: " + errorCode);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed(){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Ad closed");
                        mEditor.putInt(getString(R.string.pref_arcade_interstitial_counter), 0);
                        mEditor.apply();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `sharedPreference`doesn't have any value (null).
Try this Method

```
private void showIntAd(){
            int interstitial_counter = 
            mSharedPreferences.getInt(getString(R.string.pref_arcade_interstitial_counter), 0);
            if (interstitial_counter ==null) {
                   if (mInterstitialAd_Arcade.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd_Arcade.show();
                }
              }  
            if (interstitial_counter >= 15){
                if (mInterstitialAd_Arcade.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd_Arcade.show();
                }

                //move the listener inside oncreate .
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I dont have any issues with showing the ad, that works perfectly. My only issue is that inside the ad Listener I can't execute `mEditor` to reset my counter back to 0 ie. inputting an int of value 0

Comment: ie. if i write the following code, only 'Ad closed' will be shown in Logcat, which makes it look like `mEditor` is blocking itself and anything past it?

`@Override
            public void onAdClosed(){
                Log.i(TAG, "Ad closed");
                mEditor.putInt(getString(R.string.pref_arcade_interstitial_counter), 0);
                Log.i(TAG, "TEST");
                mEditor.apply();
                Log.i(TAG, "TEST1");
            }`

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestions, but even creating a new editor doesn't help. I get stuck already when i declare my sharedPreference `pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());`